# How do I remove days from date range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have a calendaring application I am working on in Rails 3. I am gathering a 'to' and 'from' date from the user and creating a date, and creating  events based on that range. Here is the code:

```
date_range = (params[:from_date]..params[:to_date]).to_a
date_range.each do |r|
  params[:orientation][:class_date] = r
  @orientation = Orientation.new(params[:orientation])
  @orientation.save
end
```

This works like a charm. Now I want to add check boxes in the view for Monday - Friday so the user can specify which days the want a repeating event to be created for. My thinking is to expand on the logic above and create a date range with the 'to' and 'from' dates, then remove dates based on check boxes (days) the user checks. If the user checks 'Mon', 'Wed', 'Fri', I would create my date range, then remove all Thursday and Friday dates from the range. Can anyone suggest any methods in Ruby that might be handy for dealing with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add checkboxes in your form to ignore the selected date and then ignore each day in the loop:

```
# view
<% Date::DAYNAMES.each_with_index do |day_name, wday| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "ignored_days[]", wday %>
  <%= day_name %>
<% end %>

# controller
date_range.each do |r|
  next if params[:ignored_days].include? r.wday.to_s #added edit here
  params[:orientation][:class_date] = r
  @orientation = Orientation.new(params[:orientation])
  @orientation.save
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Mr. Y, I think this is getting me close. Check out this pastie of my output. http://pastie.org/8412579 The 'next if' seems to executing for all dates.

Comment: I updated my answer (changed the `ignored_days[#{wday}]` to an array instead of a hash @Lumbee

Comment: Boom! Thanks bud..you rock. I did need to add 'to_s' to r.wday. I will edit your answer and accept. Thanx!